# Razborov's response to Almost Natural Proofs

Tags: computational-complexity, open-problems

This post is about [Natural Proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof) barrier in computational complexity.

There are two recent papers related to this. They are:

1. [Amplifying lower bounds by means of self-reducibility](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1706591.1706594) by Eric Allender and Michal Koucký,
2. [Almost-natural proofs](http://math.mit.edu/~tchow/almost.pdf) by Timothy Chow.

[Alexander Razborov](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/) mentioned them at the end of his talk in the first [Barriers Workshop](http://intractability.princeton.edu/barriers-workshop/) at IAS in 2009. The video of his talk is available [here](http://intractability.princeton.edu/blog/2009/06/program-for-barriers-in-computational-complexity-workshop/). He mentioned that a possible way to respond to these would be to make the largeness condition relative. So here is my question:

> Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: Relative in what sense?

Comment: As far as I understand, he was saying that one should redefine the largeness to be relative to the class of functions being attacked. His comments were very brief (last 5min of his talk). I will add a link to the video of his talk to the post.